# The Email Address added to List Workflow Changes to Random Characters

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, sharepoint-server, designer-workflow, email

I have a situation very weird.

I have several List workflows that will be sued within a SharePoint List. The SharePoint Site has being migrated from SharePoint 2010 to 2013. So the workflows are still working as SharePoint 2010 workflows.

But the SharePoint Workflows are working fine even if they are still SharePoint 2010.

Now I wanted to modify some of the Workflows by updating an existing email address to another.

So I tried to add this email address and it was a successful. But when I save the changes the added email address is changed to a bunch of random characters.

This happened only to this email address only. I have added a same kind of address to the same workflow but it works perfectly. I checked the email address from outlook and there's no any different in that.

I use SharePoint Designer 2013 to work with Workflows.

Could someone help me on this.

Thanks and regards,
Chiranthaka